# Python Statsmodels Holt Winters - How to use exogenous variables for forecasting?

Tags: python, time-series, statsmodels, forecasting, holtwinters

I am trying to forecast a timeseries using `ExponentialSmoothing` from `statsmodels.tsa.holtwinters`.

The [Statsmodels documentation](https://www.statsmodels.org/dev/generated/statsmodels.tsa.holtwinters.ExponentialSmoothing.html) mentions an attribute called `exog_names` which provides the names of the exogenous variables, but no information on how to pass the exogenous data to the model.

I have tried to use the following code snippet:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import itertools
from statsmodels.tsa.holtwinters import ExponentialSmoothing

#HW model setup

HW = ExponentialSmoothing(df["Number of Cars"],
                                    trend='add',
                                    seasonal='add',
                                    seasonal_periods = 2)

#Setting exogenous variables

HW.exog = exog_data[["GDP", "Fuel Price"]]
    
HW_Model = HW.fit()
    
#Forecasting

HW_Model.forecast(5)
```

When I do `HW.exog`, I get both "GDP" and "Fuel Price".

However, when I do `HW.exog_names`, "GDP" and "Fuel Price" are not returned. Is this the right way to include exogenous data in the Statsmodel Holt Winters implementation in Python?

Comment: As far as I know, all of the exponential smoothers in statsmodels do not support exogenous regressors. As a work around, you could regress on the exogenous variables and then smooth the residuals.  You would then need to reassemble to forecast components.  A lot of caution is needed here since suprious regression can be an issue if your variables are non-stationary.  The alternative is to model the series as a SARIMAX.  Most statespace models can be recast as a particular parameterization of a SARIMAX model.